# Linq Query across 3 tables

Tags: linq, entity-framework

My Domain model is as follows:

```
User  { Id, FirstName, LastName, TeamId }
Team  { Id, Name, Description }
Topic { Id, Title, UserId }
```

My application logic says that a user should be able to view all topics within his/her team.

Knowing the above, how can I write a linq query that will get all topics that have been made by people on the same team as the user?

I have tried the following, but it is obviously wrong, and I just can't see through the logic for the linq query :(

```
var topicList = (from u in context.Users
                join t in context.Topics on u.Id equals t.UserId
                where u.TeamId == id
                select new Tourist.WEB.Models.TopicListViewModel
                {
                    Id = t.Id,
                    Title = t.Title,
                    TopicAuthor = u.FirstName,
                    NoOfReplies = 3
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this:

```
from u in context.Users
join t in context.Team on u.TeamId equals t.Id
join to in context.Topic on u.id equals to.UserId
where u.TeamId == id
```

Complete query:

```
var topicList = (from u in context.Users
                 join t in context.Team on u.TeamId equals t.Id
                 join to in context.Topic on u.id equals to.UserId
                 where u.TeamId == id
                select new Tourist.WEB.Models.TopicListViewModel
                {
                    Id = to.Id,
                    Title = to.Title,
                    TopicAuthor = u.FirstName,
                    NoOfReplies = 3
                }).ToList();
```